# MySQL - SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: (conn=25) Table 'afiliados' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Tags: database, mariadb

I tried loading this as part of a larger script but its seemingly unlocked despite the explicit lock tables at the bottom.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `afiliados`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `afiliados` (
  `value1` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `value2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `value3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value4` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value5` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value7` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`value1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `afiliados`
--

LOCK TABLES `afiliados` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `afiliados` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `afiliados` VALUES ...
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `afiliados` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I expected the code to generate me a table, the result was the `SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: (conn=25) Table 'afiliados' was not locked with LOCK TABLES` error.

I tried deleting the `UNLOCK TABLES` at the bottom but it did nothing.

Comment: which MariaDB version? If removing `unlock tables` had no effect, could it be another SQL statement generating the error?

Comment: I didnt mange to find the exact problem, the issue didnt exist until I changed some values. I made my code work short term by deleting all the lock and unlock tables from the code.

Comment: Good move, if you're not doing admin like tools, `lock tables`/`unlock tables` are a hammer looking for a problem. Transactions are sufficient for most uses.